# Choosing the row with the maximum character length in sas

Tags: sas, proc-sql

I have the following dataset:

```
dataseta:
No. Name1 Name2                       Sales Inv Comp
1   TC    Tribal Council Inc          100   100  0
2.  TC    Tribal Council Limited INC  20    25   65

desired output:
    datasetb:
    No. Name1 Name2                       Sales Inv Comp
    1   TC    Tribal Council Limited Inc  120   125  0
```

Basically, I need to choose the row with the maximum length of characters for the column name2.
I tried the following, but it didn't work

```
proc sql;
create table datasetb as select no,name1,name2,sum(sales),sum(inv),min(comp) from dataseta group by 1,2,3 having length(name2)=max(length(name2));quit;
```

If I do the following code, it only partially resolves it, and I get duplicate rows

```
proc sql;
create table datasetb as select no,name1,max(length(name2)),sum(sales),sum(inv),min(comp) from dataseta group by 1,2 having length(name2)=max(length(name2));quit;
```

Comment: `having length(name2) = max(length(name2))` this should give your desired result

Comment: What do you want to do in the case of ties?

Comment: @samkart I tried your suggestions, but it didn't work. I updated my original post. Basically, it only partially resolves it, and I get duplicate rows

Comment: @Tom If it's a tie, there will be only one row. However, to your point, I tried the approach suggested the other person, but I got duplicate rows

Comment: Your attempt at the solution is trying to do much more than just select the observation with longest value of NAME2.  Plus you are deriving new variables in the select list without telling SAS what names to use for those derived variables.  If two or more observations both have a value of NAME2 with the same length what criteria do you want to use to pick between them?  What if you have two or more identical observations (such that there is no way to tell them apart)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be joining the results of two separate aggregate computations.

Presuming:

`no` is unique so as to allow a tie breaker criteria and the first (per `no`) longest `name2` is to be joined with the `cost`, `inv`, `comp` totals over `name1`.

The query will have lots going on...

- 1st longest `name2` within `name1`, nested subqueries are needed to:

  - Determine the longest `name2`, then
  - Select first one, according to `no`, if more than one.
- totals over `name1`

  - The totals will be a sub-query that is joined to, for delivering the desired result set.

**Example (SQL)**

```
data have;
length no 8 name1 $6 name2 $35 sales inv comp 8;
input 
no name1& name2&                      sales inv  comp; datalines;
1   TC    Tribal Council Inc          100   100  0    * name1=TC group
2   TC    Tribal Council Limited INC  20    25   65
3   TC    Tribal council co           0     0    0 
4   TC    The Tribal council Assoctn  10    10   10
7   LS    Longshore association       10    10   0    * name=LS group
8   LS    The Longshore Group, LLC    2     4    8
9   LS    The Longshore Group, llc    15    15   6
run;

proc sql;
  create table want as

  select 
    first_longest_name2.no,
    first_longest_name2.name1,
    first_longest_name2.name2,
    name1_totals.sales,
    name1_totals.inv,
    name1_totals.comp

  FROM

    (
      select 
        no, name1, name2 
      from 
        ( select 
            no, name1, name2 
          from have
          group by name1
          having length(name2) = max(length(name2))
        ) longest_name2s
      group by name1
      having no = min(no)
    ) as
    first_longest_name2

  LEFT JOIN 

    ( 
      select  
        name1,
        sum(sales) as sales,
        sum(inv) as inv,
        sum(comp) as comp
      from 
        have
      group by name1
    ) as
    name1_totals

  ON

    first_longest_name2.name1 = name1_totals.name1
;
quit;
```

**Example (DATA Step)**

Processing the data in a serial manner, when `name1` groups are contiguous rows, can be accomplished using a DOW loop technique -- that is a loop with a `SET` statement within it.

```
data want2;
  do until (last.name1);
    set have;
    by name1 notsorted;

    if length(name2) > longest then do;
      longest = length(name2);
      no_at_longest = no;
      name2_at_longest = name2;
    end;

    sales_sum = sum(sales_sum,sales);
    inv_sum   = sum(inv_sum,inv);
    comp_sum  = sum(comp_sum,comp);
  end;

  drop name2 no sales inv comp longest;

  rename 
    no_at_longest = no
    name2_at_longest = name2
    sales_sum = sales
    inv_sum = inv
    comp_sum = comp
  ;
run;
```